# MS SQL: NOT IN does not work as expected :-(

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a strange problem :-( I have a table with an ID 1090 in it - but when I try to exclude it from with a sqlcommand like `WHERE something AND md.vennenr NOT IN (SELECT FriendID FROM DuplicateList)` the 'NOT IN' tells me that it doesn't exists - even it does!

My complete stored procedure look like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[DuplicateLevel3] @UserID INT AS
DECLARE
    @MaxDubletNo int,
    @oldTime DateTime

WITH cte4 AS (
    SELECT t.Upper_Fornavn    
    FROM (
        SELECT *
        FROM Medlemsdata md
        WHERE md.vennenr NOT IN (SELECT FriendID FROM DuplicateList)
    ) as t
)
INSERT INTO DuplicateList (FriendID)
SELECT md.Vennenr
FROM Medlemsdata md;
```

I really hope that someone can help me out of this strange problem ...
Regards,
Michael

**Update:**

```
Table: DuplicateList has an int column FriendID:

FriendID
========
1089    
1090    
1091
```

these IDs has been filled by the 'first check ...'
but in 'second check' the CTE won't find 1090 when it check for this value.
I can inform that I don't have any NULL values in this column.

Comment: Bet there's at least 1 row where `FriendID` has the value `NULL`. If so, it's working exactly as expected and [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/in-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#result-value). Use `NOT EXISTS` not `NOT IN`.

Comment: NOT IN is fine, just  check for NULLs : `vennenr NOT IN (SELECT FriendId FROM DuplicateForgetFriends WHERE ALevelNo = 3 AND FriendId IS NOT NULL)` in subquery

Comment: @Larnu How canIuse ```NOT EXISTS``` ?

Comment: Take the time to make us a [mre] (with emphasis on the **minimal**). According to your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64932034/ms-sql-not-in-does-not-work-as-expected/64932258#comment114798444_64932258) `NOT EXISTS` didn't fix the problem, which means it's not `NOT IN` that is the problem.

Comment: @Larnu I have minimized it as far as I can ...

Comment: That's not a [mre]  @MichaelEriksen .

Comment: I have now minimized it very much...

Answer (score 1):

As I mention in the comments, this is very likely because you have at least one row where the value of `FriendID` has the value `NULL`. If so, then the behaviour you have is both expected and [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/in-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#result-value):

> ### Result Value
>
> If the value of test_expression is equal to any value returned by subquery or is equal to any expression from the comma-separated list, the result value is TRUE; otherwise, the result value is FALSE.
>
> Using NOT IN negates the subquery value or expression.
>
> > **⨂ Caution**
> >
> > Any null values returned by subquery or expression that are compared to test_expression using IN or NOT IN return UNKNOWN. Using null values in together with IN or NOT IN can produce unexpected results.

Instead, I prefer using `NOT EXISTS`, as it doesn't have the same feature. Alternatively, as Lukasz suggests, you can add a `WHERE` into the subquery:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.TableA (I int NOT NULL);
CREATE TABLE dbo.TableB (I int NULL);
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.TableA (I)
VALUES(1),(2),(3),(4),(5);
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.TableB (I)
VALUES(3),(NULL);
GO
--Returns no rows
SELECT A.I 
FROM dbo.TableA A
WHERE A.I NOT IN (SELECT B.I FROM dbo.TableB B);
GO
--Returns Rows
SELECT A.I 
FROM dbo.TableA A
WHERE A.I NOT IN (SELECT B.I FROM dbo.TableB B WHERE B.I IS NOT NULL);
GO
--Returns Rows
SELECT *
FROM dbo.TableA A
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.TableB B WHERE A.I = B.I);
GO

DROP TABLE dbo.TableA;
DROP TABLE dbo.TableB;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d2f68a9eb863ca54e6b3914730590296)

Comment: Thanks for helping - but I'm so sorry :-( It doesn't works :-( I have tried to use ```NOT EXISTS``` without any success :-(

Comment: Time for some sample data and expected results then, @MichaelEriksen, as therefore the problem isn't the `NOT IN`.

Comment: I hope I can show some sample data

Comment: I have not added a little bit sample data - I hope that it can explain it further ...